# Remove Hidden Folders from Custom Tree Folder Dialolog

Tags: c#, file, drive

I have made a custom Tree Folder dialog using a TreeView.Visit [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/13375/file-explorer-using-treeview-controller-in-c) link for the reference code.

```
 public bool CreateTree(TreeView treeView)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;

        try
        {
            // Create Desktop
            TreeNode desktop = new TreeNode();
            desktop.Text = "Desktop";
            desktop.Tag = "Desktop";
            desktop.Nodes.Add("");
            treeView.Nodes.Add(desktop);
            // Get driveInfo
            foreach (DriveInfo drv in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
            {
                TreeNode fChild = new TreeNode();
                if (drv.DriveType == DriveType.CDRom) 
                {
                    fChild.ImageIndex = 1;
                    fChild.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
                }
                else if (drv.DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
                {
                    fChild.ImageIndex = 0;
                    fChild.SelectedImageIndex = 0;
                }
                fChild.Text = drv.Name;
                fChild.Nodes.Add("");
                treeView.Nodes.Add(fChild);

                returnValue = true;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            returnValue = false;
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
```

Is there any way to remove $ folders (system hidden files like recycle bin) from this dialog? Any help would be most appreciable.

[image: Remove Hidden Files from Custom TreeFolder Dialog]

Comment: You're not showing the part of the code where you enumerate the folders! However I think you will want to look at the [DirectoryInfo.Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes(v=vs.110).aspx) on each folder and exclude those that have the `System` and/or `Hidden` flag.

Comment: @ stuartd Thank you for providing informative guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the whole source that is used for your question in the future.

You can exclude Hidden and/or system folders by leveraging the Attributes property on the DirectoryInfo and/or FileInfo objects. For this particular set of source, you can add the logic below to the EnumerateDirectory method.

Attributes.HasFlag is available in C# 4.0 and later.

```
public TreeNode EnumerateDirectory(TreeNode parentNode)
{
    ...

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in rootDir.GetDirectories())
    {
        if (dir.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden)) continue;

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```